# Xtext: refering objects from other languages; namespaces and aliases for importURI?

Tags: xtext

I'm developing a xtext-based language which should refer to objects defined in a vendor-specific file format.

E.g. this file format defines messages, my language shall define Rules that work with these messages. Of course i want to use xtext features e.g. to autocomplete/validate message names, attributes etc.

Not sure if that is a good idea, but I came up with the following:

- Use one xtext project to describe the file format
- Add a dependency for this project to my DSL project, import the file format grammar to my grammar
- import the description files via importURI

FileFormat grammar:

```
grammar com.example.xtext.fileformat.FileFormat;
generate fileformat "http://xtext.example.com/fileformat/FileFormat"
[...]
```

DSL grammar:

```
grammar com.example.xtext.dsl.DSL;
import "http://xtext.example.com/fileformat/FileFormat" AS ff;
Model:
    rules += Rule*;

Rule: ImportFileRule | SampleRule;
ImportFileRule: "IMPORT" importURI=STRING "AS" name=ID ";";
SampleRule: "FORWARD" msg=[ff::Message] ";"
```

First of all: This works fine.

Now, different imported files may define messages with colliding names, 
and I want to use fully qualified names for messages anyways.
The prefix for the message names should be defined in my DSL, e.g. the name of the ImportFileRule.

So I would like to use something like:

```
IMPORT "first-incredibly-long-filename-with-version-and-stuff.ff" AS first;
IMPORT "second-incredibly-long-filename-with-version-and-stuff.ff" AS second;

FORWARD first.msg_1; // references to msg_1 in first file
FORWARD second.msg_1; // references to msg_1 in second file
```

Unfortunately I don't see a easy way to achieve this with xtext.

At the moment I'm using a ID for the namespace qualifier and custom ProposalProvider/Validator classes,
which is ugly in detail and bypasses the EMF index, becoming slow with files of 1000 messages and 50000 attributes...

Would there be a right way to do it?
Was it a good idea to use xtext to parse the definition files in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two ideas what to check.

1. Xtext has a specific global scope provider called [ImportedNameSpaceAwareScopeProvider](http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/xtext/javadoc/2.3/org/eclipse/xtext/scoping/impl/ImportedNamespaceAwareLocalScopeProvider.html). By using an overridden version of this, you could specify other headers to consider.
2. Check the implementation of the [xtext grammar itself](https://github.com/eclipse/xtext/tree/master/plugins/org.eclipse.xtext/src/org/eclipse/xtext), as it supports such a feature with EPackage imports. I am not exactly sure, how it operates, but should work this way.

Comment: Thank you! Overriding ImportedNameSpaceAwareScopeProvider was the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I ended up using the SimpleNamesFragment, ImportURIScopingFragment and a custom ScopeProvider derived from AbstractDeclarativeScopeProvider.

That way, I had to implement ScopeProvider methods for quiet a few rules but was much more flexible in using my "namespace prefix".
E.g. it is simple to implement syntaxes like

```
FORWARD FROM first: msg_01, msg_02;
```